# Find network config from Linux

Tags: oracle-linux

I buy a VPS and use console of access to setup my Linux on it, but can’t access to network (internet) from my VPS

I have static IP address but I don’t know the gateway or mask. I don’t know anything about it just i know my IP address.

So from VMware console I can’t access to network to check this. How can I get info about my config to connect this to internet, I use automatic but not work.

I tried `route -n` but not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to query the NetworkManager (network management daemon - see `man NetworkManager). There should be a nice GUI tool in your desktop now.

Or in a terminal use `nmcli` (command-line tool for controlling NetworkManager - see `man nmcli`). For example to just see all the device's statuses:

```
nmcli device status
```

Or to see more detailed info (like IP4 & 6 addresses, gateways, route, dns...)

```
nmcli device show
```

Except from `man nmcli`:

> show [ifname]
>
> Show detailed information about devices. Without an argument, all devices are
>              examined. To get information for a specific device, the interface name has to be
>              provided.

Comment: `nmcli device show ens32` no info about gateway @Xen2050

Comment: ip4.route[1] : dst =myip/31 , nh=0.0.0.0 , mt=100

Comment: dont tell why i asking my supporter vps about it! they sleeping :D